# How to display value if query result is NULL

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Excuse me,
I have source for get value from table

```
foreach ($hard->result() as $row) {
    $ha[] = $row->bek;
  }
```

(bek is name of column and $hard isi name of variable return query)

then I wanna write the result with lopping too.

```
<?php
  '<tr>';
    $d = 0;
    $g = 0;
    $s = 0;
    foreach ($mon->result() as $row) {
  ?>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row->sNama;?></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $norm[$d++];?></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $ha[$g++];?></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $urg[$s++];?></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
    }
  ?>
```

my question is : how to give '0', when the result from db doesn't give a value (null)
Can someone help me please,,

Thanks before

Comment: `$norm,$ham,$urg` from where these variable are coming?

Comment: take a look at this function                 

[isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

Comment: Test `$mon->result()` before doing anything and depending on the result paint a table or not.

Comment: use a template engine, I also recommend better variable naming

Comment: @Anant : Actually $norm, $urg isn't necessary, thats another variable for write my result value which I got from db

Comment: @SadokMtir,Thanks so much for attention and advice. Although I have'nt solve my problem and I think it's little bit hard to explain my case,,
so I will ask someone near me ^_^

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions : Thanks so much for attention and advice. Although I have'nt solve my problem and I think it's little bit hard to explain my case,, ^_^

Comment: @Mazzy : Thanks so much for attention and advice. Although I have'nt solve my problem and I think it's little bit hard to explain my case,, ^_^

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
<?php
  '<tr>';
    $d = 0;
    $g = 0;
    $s = 0;
    foreach ($mon->result() as $row) {
  ?>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php isset($row->sNama) ? echo $row->sNama : echo '0'; ?></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php isset($norm[$d++]) ? echo $norm[$d++] : echo '0'; ?></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php isset($ha[$g++]) ? echo $ha[$g++] : echo '0'; ?></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php isset($urg[$s++]) ? echo $urg[$s++]] : echo '0'; ?></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    </tr>
  <?php
    } 

?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and attention @Jyoti, but it's not done, because I need seomething which manipulate in
foreach ($hard->result() as $row) {
    $ha[] = $row->bek; // -> In here, how to give '0' when num_rows from db is null, so how I give $ha[something] with 0
  }

Sorry If I make you confuse, because it's little bit hard to explain my case. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $res = $mon->result();
    if($res && count($res)>0){
        $d = 0;
        $g = 0;
        $s = 0;
        foreach ($res as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
                <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $row->sNama;?></td>
                <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $norm[$d++];?></td>
                <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $ha[$g++];?></td>
                <td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $urg[$s++];?></td>
                <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
            </tr>
        <?php } 
    } 
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and attention @Nitesh Gupta, but it's not done, because I need seomething which manipulate in foreach ($hard->result() as $row) { $ha[] = $row->bek; // -> In here, how to give '0' when num_rows from db is null, so how I give $ha[something] with 0 } Sorry If I make you confuse, because it's little bit hard to explain my case. Thank you

Comment: You want to manipulate on this loop

foreach ($hard->result() as $row) {
    $ha[] = $row->bek;
  }

Comment: Yeah.. but I got a mistake..

I will post in answer question

Thank you

Comment: @NiteshGupta - try to avoid code only answers... please provide a description of why / how your proposed solution resolves the OPs problem.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for all your attention to answer my case,

my problem is how to manipulate value from the table even when the value is empty

after I tried all way, I knew my case can't be fixed if I don't change my query because when I tried to loop with index 0, the result isnot still give '0'

```
foreach ($hard->result() as $row) {
    $ha[0] = $row->bek;
  }

<td class="tg-yw4l"><?php echo $ha[0];?></td>
```

because of that I knew, I should change my query in order if the result is empty it must give value '0'